# get curl: (56) Recv failure: outside container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Outside docker container (in the host) I received error responding like below.

```
**[root@localhost myfirstpythonweb]# curl http://127.0.0.1:8000**    
**curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer**        
**[root@localhost myfirstpythonweb]# docker ps**

CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             

STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES    
268b43187d06        mydocker            "gunicorn -w 2 myfir…"   23 minutes ago      Up 23 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   hungry_morse        
**[root@localhost myfirstpythonweb]# netstat -ntpl**    
Active Internet connections (only servers)    
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      11599/docker-proxy
```

netstat show the port 8000 is open but curl fail to response.

Inside container: I get proper responding.

```
[root@localhost myfirstpythonweb]# docker exec -ti 268b43187d06  /bin/bash    
**[root@268b43187d06 myfirstpythonweb]# curl http://127.0.0.1:8000**    
**Hello, World!**    
**[root@268b43187d06 myfirstpythonweb]# netstat -ntpl**    
Active Internet connections (only servers)    
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/python3.6
```

netstat show port 8000 open and curl respond works

Dockerfile:

```
FROM centos:latest    
WORKDIR /home/albert/python/myfirstpythonweb    
RUN yum install python3-virtualenv net-tools -y && \
        pip3 install gunicorn    
COPY myfirst.py myfirst.py    
EXPOSE 8000    
CMD ["gunicorn","-w", "2","myfirst:app","-b","0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Thanks

Comment: In general you need to include enough details to produce a [mcve], like the actual Dockerfile for your image.  The final line of your `netstat` output suggests that the process inside the container is bound to 127.0.0.1; you need to reconfigure it to listen to 0.0.0.0, or it will be unreachable from outside the container.

Comment: @DavidMaze Hi David, I upload Dockerfile.  I configure everything listen to 0.0.0.0 inside container. I can also see port opening in the host (outside container). Thanks

Comment: @DavidMaze I found the issues. In stead of listen to 0.0.0.0, I use 172.17.0.2. That way fixed issues.. Thanks for hints.